# Why do I still have Keyboard - English (US) in my list, if I have removed it in the Text Entry Settings?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Ubuntu 16.04

I would like to completely remove Keyboard English (US) from my keyboards, because a lot of times (while coding) I accidentally toggle the keyboard and,  annoyingly, end up typing things I don't intend to.

[Keyboard English (US) still in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpWDe.png)

[Removed in Text Entry Settings, though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVtO.png)

Sorry, apparently the site says I am not allowed to embed images?! So you will have to click the links.

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3          File: /etc/default/keyboard                           

# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="hu"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely *English (US)* is set system wide via `/etc/default/keyboard`. You can edit that file.

Comment: Interesting, but the file does not contain that, does it? I've updated my description with the content of that file.

Comment: @TeXnophobe: Hmm.. No, it doesn't. Did you relogin or reboot after having dropped English in Text Entry?

Comment: Yes, I have done this several days again and since then did reboots a couple of times.

Comment: @TeXnophobe: Another question: I don't see Sogou Pinyin in Text Entry, so I suppose you have enabled it directly via the Fcitx configuration tool (which is normally not needed in Ubuntu 16.04). Anyway, can it be that English (US) is enabled from there?